# unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'list' Python

Tags: python, random

I need to generate 10 random numbers in 2 variables and calculated the ratio between them.
My code is below. What am I doing wrong?

```
from random import randint
N=10
a = [random.randint(0, 10) for _ in range(N)]
b = [random.randint(0, 10) for _ in range(N)]
print (a,b)
ratio = a/b

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'list'
```

Comment: The diagnostic seems pretty clear to me.  The `/` operator does not accept operands of type list.  You want to compute quotients of pairs of list *elements*, not of the lists themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lists don't support arithmetic operators by default, because the elements may not be things that support arithmetic (they may not even be numbers, and they could be of mixed types!).

You'll want to do something like

```
from random import randint

N = 10
a = [random.randint(0, 10) for _ in range(N)]
b = [random.randint(0, 10) for _ in range(N)]
ratio = [ai / bi for ai, bi in zip(a, b)]

print(a, b)
print(ratio)
```

For more convenient ways to do these kinds of calculations, look into [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/).

Comment: Thanks I'm new with all of it, I'll also look into NumPy.